# Statistical test for a random die roll?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I roll a six-sided die 1000 times and write down the number of times each face comes up.  How do I test whether the die is fair?  Can I use a chi-squared test where the expected number of each face is 1000/6=167?

There also appears to be a [multinomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test), but that seems less likely to be baked into stats packages and software.

[Related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80499/can-i-use-a-chi-squared-test-to-compare-two-empirical-distributions).

Comment: You can certainly use a chi-square (but don't round off the expected value; leave it at 1000/6). Some directly relevant posts: [A](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/how-can-i-test-the-fairness-of-a-d20), $\, $ [B](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68270/how-do-i-find-data-to-show-whether-a-shaved-die-is-really-loaded), $\, $ [C](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58438/chi-squared-distribution-for-dice-not-returning-expected-values), $\, $  [D](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14301/designing-a-test-for-a-psychic-who-says-he-can-influence-dice-rolls), ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... and some potentially relevant discussion in [E](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49210/grouping-trials-decreases-standard-error). Yes, the multinomial test should work, but the chi-square should do just about as well.

Comment: A multinomial exact test could need to consider ${1005 \choose 5} = 8,\!459,\!043,\!543,\!951$ cases.  Even allowing for symmetrical possibilities, that leaves $12,\!193,\!703,\!764$ distinct cases, which is still rather large.  There are further efficiencies possible, but this is still probably not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks to all who referred me to other questions, I wasn't finding them on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the chi-square test of goodness of fit with number of possible cases - 1 degrees of freedom and the null hypothesis being the discrete uniform distribution as you pointed out. This is a textbook example for that.